# Spark 3: Partition count changing on dataframe select cols

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am noticing a difference in behaviour on upgrading to spark 3 where the NumPartitions are changing on df.select which causing my zip operations to fail on mismatch. With spark 2.4.4 it works fine. This does not happen with filter but only with select cols

```
    spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("local"). \
    master("local[2]"). \
    config("spark.executor.memory", "2g"). \
    config("spark.driver.memory", "2g"). \
    config("spark.sql.shuffle.partitions",10). \
    config("spark.default.parallelism", 10). \
    getOrCreate()
```

With Spark 2.4.4:

```
df = spark.table("tableA")
print(df.rdd.getNumPartitions()) #10
new_df = df.filter("id is not null")
print(new_df.rdd.getNumPartitions()) #10
new_2_df = df.select("id")
print(new_2_df.rdd.getNumPartitions()) #10
```

With Spark 3.0.0:

```
df = spark.table("tableA")
print(df.rdd.getNumPartitions()) #10
new_df = df.filter("id is not null")
print(new_df.rdd.getNumPartitions()) #10
new_2_df = df.select("id")
print(new_2_df.rdd.getNumPartitions()) #1
```

See the last line where it changes to 1 partition from initial 10. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Dynamic partition pruning is new in 3.0.
https://spark.apache.org/releases/spark-release-3-0-0.html

Comment: tried with the below config disabling dynamicPartitionPruning, still the same results 
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("pytest-pyspark-local-testing"). \
        master("local[5]"). \
        config("spark.executor.memory", "2g"). \
        config("spark.driver.memory", "2g"). \
        config("spark.ui.showConsoleProgress", "false"). \
        config("spark.sql.shuffle.partitions",10). \
        config("spark.sql.optimizer.dynamicPartitionPruning.enabled","false"). \
        config("spark.default.parallelism", 10). \
        getOrCreate()